# Dynamically set element height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone to render a square tile element in which I set the height and then dynamically set the width to match the height.  However, when trying to fetch the elements height, I get `0` returned.

Here is my code:

```
var app = app || {};

app.ClassModelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'tile',

    template: _.template('<%= name %>'),

    render: function() {
        var dim = 'calc(' + parseInt(100 / app.global.rows) + '% - ' + app.global.margin * (app.global.rows + 1) + 'px)'; //e.g. "30% - 20px"
        this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.attributes)).css({
            margin: app.global.margin + 'px',
            height: dim,
        }).css({
            width: this.$el.height() + 'px',
        });

        return this;
    }
})
```

How would I set the width of `$el` to the height?  I'm not sure if I'm doing something syntactically wrong or if it is the way I'm using Backbone that is resulting in my problem.

Comment: You can try using `.outerHeight(true)` instead. If it doesn't work please consider uploading your code to http://www.jsfiddle.net to show us your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran into similar issues in the past.  In most cases, it was because my view had rendered but had not yet been inserted into the DOM.  This is pretty common when dealing with nested views.

You can test for this by setting a break point in your onRender method and checking this.$el.parent().  You might want to go up a few parents to make sure the parent elements are in the DOM.

You can get around this by binding to the DOMNodeInserted event:

```
this.$el.on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) { console.log($(e.target).outerHeight()); })
```